# opaque (abstract) data types in C

Tags: c, types, abstract

#### File api.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef API
#define API

struct trytag;
typedef struct trytag try;

void trial (try *);

#endif
```

#### File core.h

```
#ifndef CORE
#define CORE
struct trytag
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
#endif
```

#### File func.c

```
#include "api.h"
#include "core.h"

void trial (try *tryvar)
{
    tryvar->a = 1;
    tryvar->b = 2;
}
```

#### File main.c

```
#include "api.h"

int main ()
{
    try s_tryvar;

    trial(&s_tryvar);

    printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", s_tryvar.a, s_tryvar.b);
}
```

When I compile, I get:

```
main.c:5: error: storage size of ‘s_tryvar’ isn’t known
```

If I include `core.h` in `main.c` this error doesn't come as try is defined in `core.h`. But I want the structure `try` to be hidden to `main.c` — it should not know the members of `try` structure. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible.  The compiler needs to know how big a `try` structure is to compile `main.c`.  If you really want it to be opaque, make a generic pointer type, and instead of declaring the variable directly in `main()`, make `alloc_try()` and `free_try()` functions to handle the creation and deletion.

Something like this:

api.h:

```
#ifndef API
#define API

struct trytag;
typedef struct trytag try;

try *alloc_try(void);
void free_try(try *);
int try_a(try *);
int try_b(try *);
void trial (try *);

#endif
```

core.h:

```
#ifndef CORE
#define CORE
struct trytag
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
#endif
```

func.c:

```
#include "api.h"
#include "core.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

try *alloc_try(void)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct trytag));
}

void free_try(try *t)
{
    free(t);
}

int try_a(try *t)
{
    return t->a;
}

int try_b(try *t)
{
    return t->b;
}

void trial(try *t)
{
    t->a = 1;
    t->b = 2;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "api.h"

int main()
{
    try *s_tryvar = alloc_try();

    trial(s_tryvar);
    printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", try_a(s_tryvar), try_b(s_tryvar));

    free_try(s_tryvar);
}
```

Comment: Yuck, do not do "typedef void try;".  When you do this, you lose type safety (the compiler will not be able to catch such nonsense as `int x; trial(&x);`  The question technique of introducing a new struct is much better.

Comment: The part about allocating an instance is right on, but I wonder how main.c is supposed to dereference the a and b when all it has is api.h, not core.h.  I don't think that's ever going to work without func.c exposing some access helper methods.

Comment: For real safety, you probably want to allocate and populate some identification fields in the `alloc_try()` function.  That way you can check if a structure you pass in works.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - Yes. We can't dereference s_tryvar in printf. It should be commented.

Comment: @Carl Norum: Yes, that's a great idea.  And if the overhead offends, it can be compiled out when not in DEBUG mode.  If this were C++, I'd suggest using dynamic_cast instead.

Answer (score 1):

Think how the opaque FILE structure works in C. You only work with  pointers, and you need a function like fopen() to create an instance, and a function like fclose() to dispose of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in main.c, the compiler hasn't seen the definition of `struct try`.  Because of that, the compiler is limited to using pointers to `struct try`.

What you want to do is add two new functions to your API:

```
try *create_try();
void *destroy_try(try *t);
```

These functions will call malloc and free respectively.

If you don't want to limit your structure to only being allowed on the heap, you are going to have to give up on making it opaque.

Comment: Or hide the fact that it's on the heap by returning a non-opaque struct that contains the opaque pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something that technically is not exactly what you are asking for, but should serve the same purpose of keeping your structure opaque while supporting non-heap allocation.

in api.h, you state an opaque structure as follows:

```
struct trytag_opaque
{
    char data[sizeof(int)*2];
};
```

if you wanted to be more opaque than that, you could calculate the maximum size of the structure required across any supported platform, and use:

```
struct trytag_opaque
{
    char data[MAX_TRYTAG_SIZE];
};
```

Then your api.h function declarations would look like:

```
int try_a(struct trytag_opaque *t)
```

and your function code would look like:

```
int try_a(struct trytag_opaque *t_opaque) {
    trytag *t = (trytag *)t_opaque;
    ...
}
```

and your main.c would look like:

```
#include "api.h"
int main() {
    struct trytag_opaque t;
    ...
    try_a(&t);
    ...
}
```

Comment: And you might add an `assert(sizeof(struct trytag_opaque) >= sizeof(trytag));` somewhere appropriate — maybe even a `static_assert` if you've got C11 to play with.

Comment: to further tailor the solution, you could have a helper program that prints the size of the private structure to stdout, then pipe the helper function output to a code snippet that is included in the header file and that defines the necessary size. The snippet generation can all be managed in the Makefile. A minor pain to set up at first-- maybe 15 minutes-- but reusable for all private structures, and the sizes would always be appropriate for the given platform

Comment: btw the helper-program approach only works if you are compiling natively on each platform. not so good for cross-compiling