# C modify const members in a struct

Tags: c, casting, struct, constants

I am designing an API and the key part of it is a struct returned by the API with lots of const members. Also, there are both const pointers and pointers to const variables. Inside the implementation I need to modify this struct. Currently, I have defined exactly the same struct but with dropped const keywords and a different name. Inside the API calls I just cast external struct to the internal one.

Is there any way to code in a better way? The current design is prone to errors if I modify one struct and forget about the other.

Comment: Why not keep one instance of the struct definition (the non-const one) and return a `const` instance of the struct?  Why do you need two versions?

Comment: Use a macro to apply the const conditionally?

Comment: Use [opaque structs and accessor functions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001637/opaque-abstract-data-types-in-c

Comment: cdhowie - some members are meant to be modified and some don't.  David Heffernan - how can I do this? Doug Currie - The struct is pretty complex, lots of getters and setter will mess up the code.

Comment: @Michal er, with #ifdef and #define but I find macros make me want to puke

Answer (score 5):

Use [opaque structs and accessor functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001637/opaque-abstract-data-types-in-c)

The opaque structs provide a name for your API, but no way to address the fields.

The accessor functions in your API provide whatever controlled access you like.

Comment: You can take this a step further and have the `API` struct make the _"user accessible"_ fields top-level members and hide other details in an opaque pointer member.

Comment: This will mess up the API. I would have to add lots of extra functions. The const members are read-only, not opaque.

Comment: This answer is the best. If you really cannot use it, perhaps break the struct into const and non-const parts.  If you post more details of the interface maybe someone will have other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here: These field aren't really non writable.
You want to make them kinda "private" but every programmer can access them this way:

```
typedef struct
{
    const int x;
}mystruct;
```

Then:

```
mystruct ms= {0};
*((int*)&(ms.x)) =4;
printf("%d",ms.x);
```

Because the const specifier just prevents programmers from modifying them at compile time.But at runtime the memory isn't readonly.

I still think that the const specifier is useful: if a good programmer sees it, says then I shouldn't access that field.If instead wants to make the smart guy access the fields and potentially risk an inconsistent state.
So if you are sure that these const field can be changed, at your place I would use this way.I know that pedantic programmer will not like it, I don't like it too but sometimes we gotta bypass this.

Comment: I think this is undefined behaviour due to modifying a const object (although the C standard isn't perfectly clear)

Answer (score -1):

Duplication is the root of all evil, so instead of duplicating the structure definition you could do something like this:

```
#ifndef CONST
#define CONST const
#endif

struct mystruct
{
    CONST void * my_data;
};
```

Now you just define `CONST` to be empty before including the header file in the private implementation.

However, like the other answers suggest, this is not a very good idea. First there's probably better and cleaner ways of acheiving what you want. Second this could lead to strange and unwanted results as the compiler may use the constness of the fields to optimize the code.

In short, I think you would be better off rethinking your API.

Comment: The only drawback is that the PRIVATE_CONST in the public API can make it a bit unclear.

Comment: Just an example name, how about just CONST or MYAPI_CONST (where MYAPI is the name for your API?)

Comment: CONST is still not a valid C keyword but I seems quite good. Maybe there is a way to have duplicated struct and check if they are the same using some macros or during the building using Makefile?

Comment: No, it's not a valid C keyword, and you should not redefine those either (not sure if you can, even.) Anyways, it's just an example to show the technique, not a best practice for naming the thing :)

Comment: As discussed elsewhere, this is illegal. You must not use the same structure, in different places, with different "constness". If you tell the compiler something is "const", then it will believe that it can not change once you've made a copy of (into a register for example). So it will keep using an old value of something...

Comment: @MatsPetersson, good point. I'll make the warning at the end a bit stronger.